# Linking error in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, macos, linker, xcode4

I know this is a long shot but, I've been having trouble with a linker error that I specifically don't understand. Please refer to the picture below.

[image]

The project contains 4 targets. This error points specifically to one target that is a BSD/Shell helper tool written in `c`.

I'm sorry for being vague, as I don't fully understand what might be the problem. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Has the source file that defines `main()` been added to the helper tool target?

Comment: Yes, the helper tool is one `.m` file that has `main()` defined in it.

Comment: Are you able to build the helper tool without using Xcode?

Comment: I know the helper tool once worked because I've used it before in another project. I haven't made any changes to it since. This was in Xcode3. I am now using the same tool in Xcode4. I've noticed that the BSD/Shell app is now renamed to `Command line tool` in Xcode4. I'm assuming it is the same thing.

Comment: In the build setting, I've always had it at `i386` and `x86_64` architectures. I just removed the helper tool and went through the same laborious task of putting back into the project and it `magically` fixed itself. I don't really know, why. Perhaps it was a check box that I didn't check initially. Anyways the error is gone now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this means that the source file that defines `main()` hasn’t been added to the corresponding target.

Another possible reason is that the source file that contains `main()` is being compiled for an architecture (e.g. i386 only) but the target/executable specifies a different architecture (e.g. x86_64 only or fat/universal).

One strategy to help with diagnosing this issue is running `xcodebuild` against your project+target to inspect the commands that are being issued to compile and link the target.

When all else fails, remove the target and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include` the appropriate files?

Comment: I believe so. I've rechecked multiple times. The error is so cryptic that I've been checking everything that I can.

Comment: Also make sure that you've linked against the correct frameworks.